# Gradle DSL method not found: 'kapt()'

Tags: android, gradle, kapt

Gradle DSL method not found: 'kapt()'
Possible causes:
The project 'jetpacklearn' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.4.0 and sync project

The project 'jetpacklearn' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

My gradleVersion is '3.4.0', but can not deal with it , ask me the same question

```
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradleVersion"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's a valid question, and you run into this error message by following the official Android documentation. What's more, the built-in suggestion in the error message is confusing and wrong (talking about upgrading to Gradle 1.0 when we're on version 3.x).

Answer (score 229):

Check if you have this in top of your app build.gradle?

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Comment: Android's official doc told me to use kapt in depedencies { } without ever mentioning this. good job google.

Answer (score 89):

add this line

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

if you used kapt in **android library** you must add **kotlin-android** plugin in your project

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This was my issue.  Even the Android docs for getting started with Hilt did not mention this.  https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android

Answer (score 34):

just add this line in your app-level of build.grale :

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

**NOTE: under** `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Comment: NOTE.... mentioned here is very powerful. I never thought the order of the plugins matters. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 24):

Add this in your build.gradle then sync the gradle again.

> apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

Answer (score 16):

Your build.Gradle file should have these at the top

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 7):

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56101024/6007104 is absolutely correct.

But, for people using the gradle plugins block, it looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id('kotlin-kapt')
}
```

Answer (score 5):

apply the below plugin in your app-level build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are missing apply 'kotlin-kapt' in app level gradle.
There is two ways to add this plugin.

if your project having plugin block. please add like below.

```
plugins {
    ...
    ...
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

or you can add by using apply key word.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are missing something in gradle.
if your using kotlin DSL add this

in project-level build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
   id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version ("1.8.21-1.0.11") apply false
}
```

in app_level build.gradle.kts file

```
plugins {
   id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}
```

and add those dependencies

```
 implementation("androidx.room:room-common:2.5.2")
 implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2")
 ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")
```